# Where to find the saved folder using "Action Extension" in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

Where will be the folder of saved document using "Action Extension" in iOS?
The path is like this "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/8C1C924C-071A-4D4B-8C34-0380C81661C5/Documents/myfile" but I'm not able to find using Xcode with device connected -> Window -> Devices -> App -> ShowContainer. 
Please can anyone help me??
Same code if I run in simulator I m getting file.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your group container to access from Extension and your app.

```
FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.your.app.bundle.here")
```